# Run test in IDE NetBeans

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, netbeans

I'm sorry but I'm studying
Faced with the problem on test runs from IDE to FF 32. On Virtual Machine (VirtualBox) tests are run (where I run the selenium-server-standalone-2.43.0) everything OK!!!

And start with IDE Netbeans, just open a browser and nothing else happens. After the test falls

```
Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary (/ usr / bin / firefox) on port 7055; process output follows
```

But the / usr / bin / firefox looked there present binary

Sin on the fact that in my pom file is connected firefox-driver-2.42.2 (2.43.0 connect but does not work with the source code repository tightened http: //repo1.maven.o...org/seleniumhq/ and I NetBeans sees only the latest version 2.42.2 jar and 2.43.0 pom)

Also tried to connect firefox-driver-2.43.0 pom nothing has changed.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.43.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
  <version>2.43.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What if you downgrade Firefox from 32 to 31?

Comment: Why do you have spaces in the Firefox path name?